Help with date formula
I am trying to create a date formula that will automatically roll over 365 days once the date has passed. I have a compliance report that is due annually on the anniversary date of the contract start date so I would like to have a field that shows something like "next report due: 7/1/2024" then after that day has passed, have the field automatically roll over to show the next report is due on 7/1/2025. I have scoured the forums and not found this specific use case yet. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Below is a Formula you can use:

IF(    TODAY() > DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(Contract_Start_Date__c),
DAY(Contract_Start_Date__c)),    DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) + 1,
MONTH(Contract_Start_Date__c),     DAY(Contract_Start_Date__c)),
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(Contract_Start_Date__c),
DAY(Contract_Start_Date__c)) )

Replace Contract_Start_Date__c with the API name of the field that holds the contract start date in your org.
This formula checks if today's date is after the anniversary date for the current year. If it is, it calculates the anniversary date for the next year. If today's date is before the anniversary date, it shows the current year's date.

The important point to note: this works as long as we assume the contract starts this year or started before today. Otherwise it's a good answer covering on-going anniversaries.

I would break down this into 2 separate use cases:

When Start_date__c is less than today's date we need the field value to be rolled over by 1 year i.e. 12 months

When Start_date__c is greater than or equal to today's date field value needs to be same as Start_date__c


Keeping in mind the above two use cases, below formula can be used :
IF(
  Start_date__c  < TODAY() , 
  ADDMONTHS(Start_date__c,12) , 
  Start_date__c
)

If you are using a date/time field just wrap it in DATEVALUE() function.

This only works for a single year, not on-going anniversaries.

@PhilW: The assumption is that Start_date__c will be updated with required date always which will take care of anniversaries. Added this answer since the next report date needs to be based on Start_date__c and not continuous  anniversaries.

I have a compliance report that is due annually on the anniversary date of the contract  - IMO this sentence means that date of contract will be updated every year.

Nothing says the start date would be updated, just that there's a report to be generated on anniversaries. The first anniversary is addressed with your solution, but the second and subsequent are not. The contract may be multi-year, rather than annual.

@PhilW: I do not want to argue but again read this statement - I have a compliance report that is due annually on the anniversary date of the contract. Annually is the important word here. So  the contract is not multi-year as you are suggesting.

My point is that you can have an annual compliance report on a multi-year contract. It's just a compliance report. Regardless, the OP can choose whichever works for them from the solutions provided.

Even take an example from your own org. For example, do you sign the annual compliance every year at the exact same date ? After each compliance is signed, the signed date is stored in backend which is used to calculate future date. I understand that your POV is also correct but my answer is not intended for anniversaries as mentioned in the first comment.

@PhilW: You should have been neutral before itself like your previous comment. Anyways, I understand that there are bullies everywhere. No problem.

Sorry if you felt I was "bullying" you - I was (tersely) pointing out that your solution works for just the one year; the other solution considers repeated need for new compliance reports on an annual basis with no expectation that the underlying contract is only a year long or that the start date gets updated annually. I've not downvoted your answer, but instead pointed out the limitation and upvoted the other solution (where I also pointed out a minor limitation/gap).

No need to be sorry. You have the reputation so you have leverage to comment as you feel.Thanks for the feedback.

I again apologise for making you feel bullied; most definitely not the intent. I was simply pointing out a limitation of the solution, from my perspective.

No problem sir. Thank you for the feedback.
